# Can Google Drive Android Drive.API Android be combined with other API's?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

In [Accessing Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client) it is stated

> You can add multiple APIs and multiple scopes to the same
>   GoogleApiClient by appending additional calls to addApi() and
>   addScope().

Along this line I have tried something like that:

```
private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // Required for AppFolder access
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)     // I added this because I need Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(client) method
        .build();
}

public void onClickBtnDeleteFromDrive(View v) {
    mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

As you see I try to combine two API, because I need Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(client) method. Why? Because GoogleApiClient does not have a method to cleanly logout a default user account. Yes I know there is clearDefaultAndRecconect(), but this requires already to be signed in and also forces reconnect. Both are against my workflow.
The above buildGoogleApiClient() produces an exception:

```
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testgoogleapi/com.example.testgoogleapi.ActivityMain}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not set scopes in GoogleApiClient.Builder when using Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API. Set account in GoogleSignInOptions.Builder instead.
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not set scopes in GoogleApiClient.Builder when using Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API. Set account in GoogleSignInOptions.Builder instead.
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zza(Unknown Source)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zzoZ(Unknown Source)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.example.testgoogleapi.ActivityMain.buildGoogleApiClient(ActivityMain.java:81)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.example.testgoogleapi.ActivityMain.onCreate(ActivityMain.java:458)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
02-14 08:49:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     ... 11 more
02-14 08:49:22.710: I/Process(5436): Sending signal. PID: 5436 SIG: 9
```

So how to combine those two API's and use functionalities from both?

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the solution as well. You need to initialize the scopes using `GoogleSigninOptions`

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                   .requestScopes(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER)
                   .build()
```

Then pass this to the google api client builder so that your code will look like this

```
... rest of the code
    GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)             
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)     // Pass the GoogleSignInOptions object here
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Sign in for android --> This is Best practice as of Marshmallow

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
.requestEmail()
.build();

// Build a GoogleApiClient with access to GoogleSignIn.API and the options above.

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.enableAutoManage(this, this)
.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
.build();

Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInInten(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Result:

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

// Result returned from launching the Intent from
// GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);

if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        // Get account information
        mFullName = acct.getDisplayName();
        mEmail = acct.getEmail();
    }
}
}

@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

// Result returned from launching the Intent from

if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        // Get account information
        mFullName = acct.getDisplayName();
        mEmail = acct.getEmail();
    }
}
```

You can add multiple APIs and multiple scopes to the same GoogleApiClient by appending additional calls to addApi() and addScope().

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client

Comment: The problem with this proposal is that it does not combine with Google Drive API. And, as it turned out GoogleSignInApi does not offer any optioun to clear default account. So it has the same fault as Drive API.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}

private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Access Revoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```